# default viewport width of browser

Tags: html

All:

I am pretty to HTML tag, when I try to follow the tutorial on Udemy about web optimization, there is one lecture says if I do nto set viewport tag, the browser will use 980px as default viewport width, so if I have a body with style `width :100%;` then it will be 100% of the viewport, but when I use that, it actually just fill the window, nothing related to 980px, could anybody give me any detail about what is wrong?

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud884/lessons/1464158642/concepts/15290985620923

Answer (score 0):

He said "typically", that does not mean it has to hold for your tested browser. Also, this hold mainly for mobile browsers. So if you check this out at a desktop browser, a body of 100% width, is 100% width, I have never seen a browser which sets its viewport to less.